# How to define 'marginal distribution' in GenOrd package?

Tags: r, random, correlation

I'm trying to generate ordinal correlated variables with `GenOrd` package. However, there are some problems.

I'm getting help on this page, which was written by Wesley

https://www.r-bloggers.com/simulating-random-multivariate-correlated-data-categorical-variables/

In this page, and most of other explanation about GenOrd package, the marginal distirbution must be set. In this page, the marginal distribution is

```
#The values are cumulative so for the first variable the first marginal will be .1, the second is .2, the third is .3, and the fourth is .4
marginal <- list(c(0.1,0.3,0.6),c(0.4,0.7,0.9))
> marginal
[[1]]
[1] 0.1 0.3 0.6

[[2]]
[1] 0.4 0.7 0.9
```

However, as far as I Know, the marginal distribution is as follows. (from English wikipedia)

[image]

So the sum of marginal probability is 1. However, in the second list in marginal object, the sum is 0.4+0.7+0.9=2

How can I interpret this object?

Comment: The comment just above the code line that creates the `marginal` list says: *The values are cumulative so for the first variable the first marginal will be .1, the second is .2, the third is .3, and the fourth is .4* . So `diff(c(0, marginal[[2]], 1))` gives you the original marginal values. What the package needs seems to be the result of the `cumsum` that follows: `d <- diff(c(0, marginal[[2]]));cumsum(d)`.

Comment: really thanks! I understand it.

Comment: And the other question is...

Comment: Oh i'm sorry. While I was editing my comment, I found that the results of cumsum was inverse cumulative sum of 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4. Thanks!