# Generate a random ordinal variable correlated to existing data

Tags: r, simulation, correlation

I'm using GenOrd package to generated random ordinal variable.

With previous text, I managed to run `GenOrd` Package.

https://www.r-bloggers.com/simulating-random-multivariate-correlated-data-categorical-variables/
[How to define 'marginal distribution' in GenOrd package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56802094/how-to-define-marginal-distribution-in-genord-package?noredirect=1#comment100218159_56802094)

However, I can't find how to generate random ordinal variable with 'existing' data. In my knowledge, `GenOrd` only generated totally new variables.

Let's take an example, I generate 'previous' variable with its marginal distribution is 0.5 for 1, 0.1 for 2, 0.4 for 3.

```
set.seed(1001)
previous<-sample(c(1, 2, 3), size = 100, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.5, 0.1, 0.4))
previous

  [1] 2 1 1 1 1 3 1 1 1 3 1 1 3 1 1 3 1 1 1 3 3 1 2 3 1 3 3 1 2 1 3 2 2 1 1 1 1 3 3 1 1 1 3 1 2 1 3 1 3 3 1 1 1 3 3 3 1 1 1 2
 [61] 3 3 3 1 1 3 2 1 1 1 2 3 2 3 1 1 1 3 3 1 1 3 3 1 3 3 1 1 1 1 3 3 1 1 3 2 3 2 2 1
```

and I will generate new variable, and I will suppose its correltation with previous variable is 0.8. So correlation matrix is

```
> R <- matrix(c(1,0.8,0.8,1),2,2)
> R
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]  1.0  0.8
[2,]  0.8  1.0
```

In this situation, How can I generate new ordinal variable with exsiting data? If there is other way better than using `GenOrd` package, I would really appreciate all your help.

Comment: you might want to try your luck at Cross Validated https://stats.stackexchange.com/ to understand the theory before implementation

Comment: Well, I posted this question on Cross Validated, the question was holded, due to the off-topic.
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/415651/generate-a-random-ordinal-variable-correlated-to-existing-data

Comment: u cant just copy and paste. you need to ask it like a stats question. search if there are questions on how do I generate random ordinal variable that is correlated with a fixed value vector or something like this. and you had a stats professor and stats consultant looking at your post, so it might be interesting to them